# Bad installation of Uglify (Node-based JavaScript minifier)

Tags: javascript, npm

I want to install [Uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js) in order to minify JavaScript files on the command line. Some sources say to install `npm` and then use `npm install uglify-js -g`. Some sources say you can just `apt-get install node-uglify`.

I've uninstalled them and reinstalled them both multiple times, and at this point I have two installations, neither of which work, or even tell me what version they are. First I have the npm-installed command in `/usr/local/bin/uglifyjs`, which does nothing:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/uglifyjs --version
$ echo "if(1)x=x+1" | /usr/local/bin/uglifyjs
$
```

I also have the apt-get install in `/usr/bin/uglifyjs`, and it does minify JavaScript, but none of the command-line options work. It seems to interpret any option as a filename and then throw an error when it can't find it.

```
$ echo "if(1)x=x+1" | uglifyjs
x+=1;
$ echo "if(1)x=x+1" | uglifyjs --comment all

/usr/bin/uglifyjs:228
        if (err) throw err;
                       ^
Error: ENOENT, open '--comment'
$ uglifyjs --version

/usr/bin/uglifyjs:228
        if (err) throw err;
                       ^
Error: ENOENT, open '--version'
```

Is there any way to fix either of these? Thanks in advance.